# What's the best way to cache a website on nginx server with SSL?

Tags: ssl, reverse-proxy, cache, varnish, pound

I have a wordpress blog which runs using nginx (SSL) + PHP-FPM + MySQL. I wondered what was the best way to cache this kind of site.

I heard that Pound and Varnish do that well, but I haven't found any good documentation about how to set that up...

Is there any way easier than Pound/Varnish (and as good)? If not, how do I set that up ? Is there any good documentation ?

Answer (score 1):

Mehdi -

Caching content for a webserver that serves HTTPS content will require a reverse proxy server that can handle the HTTPS requests and reroute them as HTTP requests to a caching server before being directed to your nginx server. I have not done this with your exact scenario, but have done something similar with Apache as the reverse proxy for other Apache software, and it isn't terribly complicated.

Here is a link to a guide for setting up Pound and Varnish that should help:

https://www.zivtech.com/blog/implementing-pound-varnish-lamp-setup-achieve-secure-http-acceleration

The guide uses Apache, but you can simply substitute the Apache server with your nginx server (there won't be any changes to make on the nginx server to make it work.